Is it possible to set the scroll position before OnAfterRenderAsync in a Blazor WebAssembly application?
In a Blazor WebAssembly application, I want to set the scroll position before the page fully renders. I understand that in single-page applications (SPA), the DOM is created dynamically, and the scroll position defaults to the top. This can create a slightly awkward user experience, especially if I need to position the view at a specific region when entering or returning to the page after viewing details or editing a record. Currently, users see the page load and then have to scroll to the required section.
Is there a way to set the scroll position before rendering in Blazor WebAssembly, or any other technique to prevent this visible jump?
Thank you for any suggestions or alternative solutions you can share!

There's no built in way to get/set scroll position in blazor. You could try following js interop sample register method execute before navigation to save the postion. Dispose the register when leave the page.
Install Blazored.SessionStorage.
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();

@page "/"

@using Blazored.SessionStorage
@inject NavigationManager NAVI
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@inject ISessionStorageService SessionStorage

@for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    <p >@i</p>
}
<script>
    function getPosition() {
        return window.scrollY;
    };

    function setPosition(y) {
        window.scrollTo(0, y);
    };
</script>

@code {

    private IDisposable? _locationChangingRegistration;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _locationChangingRegistration=NAVI.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(OnLocationChanging);
        var scrollPosition = await SessionStorage.GetItemAsync<int>("position");
        if (scrollPosition == null)
        {
            scrollPosition = 0;
        }
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setPosition", scrollPosition);
    }

    private async ValueTask OnLocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        var scrollPosition = await JS.InvokeAsync<int>("getPosition");

        await SessionStorage.SetItemAsync<int>("position", scrollPosition);
        _locationChangingRegistration.Dispose();

    }
}


Thank you for your response; I really appreciate it. Your scroll positioning approach works, but only after the page renders. I’m trying to hide the scroll movement as it goes from position 0 to the target position.
I’m testing another method (still without success), by setting the body scroll style to transparent before rendering, using scrollbar-color: transparent transparent, and restoring the color after.
I’ll use your example to create a navigation controller that manages NavigationManager events. I’ll try this approach to see how it goes.

After thorough investigation, I realized that the issue wasn’t directly related to navigation but rather to a style that impacts scroll behavior in the MudBlazor library. Specifically, the following CSS is predefined in MudBlazor:


@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    :root {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
}



This smooth scroll behavior can cause a visible "jump" effect for users. The solution was to override this style as follows:


@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    :root {
        scroll-behavior: auto !important;
    }
}



With this adjustment, the issue was completely resolved. I also noticed that the default Blazor templates exhibit similar behavior, so it might be worth reviewing and tweaking this style if you encounter the same problem.
I hope this solution helps others dealing with a similar issue. Thanks to everyone for your suggestions and insights!
